# Why I am getting error while using apply map function in python to replace unwanted character in header name

Tags: python, pandas

Why I am getting error while using apply map function in python to replace unwanted character in header name?

**My DF's headers (names) contain:**

```
Day % Change        $ Opening_Price         $ Close_Price
```

**What I want is:**

```
Day Change      Opening_Price       Close_Price
```

**That is with out % sign and $ sign in the names.**

**What I am trying:**

```
DF = DF.applymap(lambda x: x if not '$' in str(x) else x.replace('$', ''))
DF = DF.applymap(lambda x: x if not '%' in str(x) else x.replace('%', ''))
```

But above gives me an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe3' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and then remove start and end whitespaces by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) if necessary:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('[$%]', '').str.strip()
```

---

```
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Day % Change, $ Opening_Price, $ Close_Price]
Index: []

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('[$%]', '').str.strip()

print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Day  Change, Opening_Price, Close_Price]
Index: []
```

Comment: Perfect... it worked... but are there alternatives as well...? just for the curiosity...

Comment: Alternative can be `df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace('[$%]', '', regex=True)`

Comment: Or maybe with `map` - `df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.replace('%', '').replace('$', ''))`

Comment: You are rocking... I never thought we can do data cleaning these ways.. thanks so much...

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck! (and please dont forget accept)